# Issue with Certificate enrollment API in WIndows 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, windows-10, csr, certenroll

I'm trying to use CertEnroll in a website to create CSRs. It works fine on the latest versions of Internet Explorer up to IE11, except when this is running on Windows 10.

I've got the CertEnroll object on my page like this:

```
<object classid="clsid:884e2049-217d-11da-b2a4-000e7bbb2b09" id="objectClassFactory" height="0" width="0" ></object>
```

My problem shows when I try to get the CSPs. I get the object like this in javascript:

```
function getCSPs() {

    var strProvider = "";
    var objCspInfos = objectClassFactory.CreateObject('X509Enrollment.CCspInformations');
    objCspInfos.AddAvailableCsps();

//[...]
}
```

This code works totally fine in IE11 before Windows 10, but with this OS `objectClassFactory` is empty and I get the following error:

```
CreateObject method is not defined in the objectClassFactory
```

I haven't been able to find any information about this problem with this specific configuration. All the posts I could find refer to IE11 on Windows 7 or 8, but in those versions of Windows this problem doesn't manifest. The only post I could find with the same problem is [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/814f0e76-04f0-4788-8e82-c1e28fedea8d/issue-with-certificate-enrolment-api-in-windows-10?forum=ieextensiondevelopment), but the only answer points to a post from 2009, which obviously doesn't bring a solution to my problem.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Do you find the solution?